# How to take inner array with limit in mongo db using php?

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

Take inner array of mongo document using with `limit` and `skip` in php.

```
$db->users->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId('5045fa0213cfcdfc06000008')));
```

Above query will give me below mongo array

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 5045fa0213cfcdfc06000008
)
[items] => Array (
    [0] => 13
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 7
    [4] => 10
    [5] => 11
    [6] => 28
    [7] => 54
    [8] => 31
    [9] => 33
    [10] => 37
    [11] => 12
)
```

Is it possible to make use of `limit` with `skip` with above mongo doc, something like below

```
$db->users->
  findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId('5045fa0213cfcdfc06000008')))->
    limit(5)->skip(5);
```

Which will output as

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 5045fa0213cfcdfc06000008
)
[items] => Array (
    [5] => 11
    [6] => 28
    [7] => 54
    [8] => 31
    [9] => 33
)
```

And how to take total count of `items` array using mongo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `limit()` and `skip()` methods only apply at the document level, not the array level.

You can use the [`$slice` operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-RetrievingaSubrangeofArrayElements) to fetch a subset of an array:

```
$skip = 5;
$limit = 5;

$filter = array('_id' => new MongoId('5045fa0213cfcdfc06000008'));
$slice = array('items' => array( '$slice' => array( $skip, $limit ) ));

$db->users->findOne($filter, $slice);
```

There currently (as at MongoDB 2.2.0) isn't a straightforward way to determine the size of the array without fetching it.  You could do some manipulation using the new [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/) but that's perhaps overkill.

A common usage pattern is to use [`$inc`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24inc) to adjust a counter in a document in the same update when items are added or removed from an array.

> And how to take total count of items array using mongo?

Here is a quick example using the Aggregation Framework in the `mongo` shell:

```
db.users.aggregate(
    { $unwind: '$items' },
    { $group: {
        '_id': '$_id',
        itemcount: { $sum: 1 }
    }}
)
```

Comment: You may wish to watch/vote on the related request [SERVER-4376: Determining array and document size (number of keys) without loading document to client](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4376) in the MongoDB issue tracker.

Comment: `$slice` will work on version `1.8+`. Is it? I am currently using `v1.4.4`. Which I think is pretty old. Due to some problems, the mongo upgrade is not done of an old project. Is there any way to do this with v1.4.4?

Comment: Wow, MongoDB 1.4.4 is rather ancient (June, 2010 .. or four major production releases and a bunch more point releases ago).  The `$slice` operator first appeared in the 1.6 production release (August, 2010) so if upgrading is out of the question you'll have to fetch the entire array and do the manipulation in your PHP code.  If you are asking questions about 1.4.4, it would be worth mentioning this in your SO questions as features have improved significantly since then :).  What version of the PHP driver are you using?

Comment: My PHP driver version is `5.3.3`

Comment: @JustinJohn: I was actually referring to the `Mongo` PHP driver/extension version.  There have been [quite a few changes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/changelog.mongo.php) in the driver since 2010, as well.

Comment: Thankyou Stennie, for your valuable help.